# How to save/share scaled down image without getting blurred

Tags: ios, iphone, image-processing, uiimage, image-resizing

I have a genuine question. I have used the following algorithm for image resizing and sharing.

```
func resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {

    let horizontalRatio = newSize.width / size.width
    let verticalRatio = newSize.height / size.height

    let ratio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
    let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * ratio, height: size.height * ratio)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, 0)
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: newSize))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

```
func shareImageToSM(image : UIImage) {

    let imageToShare = [ image ]

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    //New Excluded Activities Code
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.openInIBooks]
    } else {
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.addToReadingList]
    }
    //

    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It resizes the image correctly. Like it scales down my 600x600 image into 150x150
But When I try to save or share that scaled down image it gets the same size as of actual image but gets blurred. Please see the following images.
[image: Actual image size and dimensions]

The above is Actual image size and dimensions of 600x600
[image: Resized image size and dimensions]

And this the resized picture (150x150) that is saved/shared.
I want this image to be saved/shared in 150x150 dimension but in actual higher pixel quality like the following image. Please help me, this is a severe problem and headache for me.
[image]

Comment: Can you post your code for share?

Comment: done @ReinierMelian I am using UIActivityViewController for image sharing/saving.

Comment: The important part of your code (the saving) is missing, isn't it?

Comment: @Trilarion No, UIActivityViewController allows you to save the attached image directly to gallery as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 enum ImageQuality:CGFloat {
    case iq_50 = 50, iq_100 = 100 ,iq_320 = 320, iq_480 = 480 , iq_640 = 640 , iq_720 = 720 , iq_1024 = 1024
}
static func scaleImage(sourceImage: UIImage, imageQuality:ImageQuality) -> UIImage{
    let finalSize:CGSize = getNewsize(sourceSize: sourceImage.size, targetSize: imageQuality.rawValue)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(finalSize, false, 0)
    sourceImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: finalSize))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
static func getNewsize(sourceSize:CGSize, targetSize:CGFloat) -> CGSize{
    let width: CGFloat = sourceSize.width
    let height: CGFloat = sourceSize.height
    var scaleFactor: CGFloat = 0.0
    var scaledWidth: CGFloat = targetSize
    var scaledHeight: CGFloat = targetSize

    let widthFactor: CGFloat = targetSize / width
    let heightFactor: CGFloat = targetSize / height

    if widthFactor > heightFactor {
        scaleFactor = widthFactor
    }
    else {
        scaleFactor = heightFactor
    }
    scaledWidth = width * scaleFactor
    scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor
    return CGSize(width: scaledWidth, height: scaledHeight)
}
```

Comment: Vaneet You are almost using the same source code which I used. You just added a function to calculate new size of scaled image. My problem is not with image size, my problem is why it is saved/displayed a blur image? It like saving a 150x150 image on 600x600 canvas size. It should reduce the canvas size to 150x150 as well.